# upgrade Symfony 2.8 to 3.4 increase peak memory usage

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.8, symfony-3.4

A simple form rendered in the same bundle in the same computer  BUT with different symfony versions.

Profiler sf2.8[image]

Profiller for sf3.4
[image]
What is wrong? What has changed to double the peack memory usage in one simple form (and ofcourse the rest of pages in my local site) from one version to other?

Edit. Before reboot computert sf3.4 has lower memory usage, but is still bigger than sf28

Comment: Tons of stuff have changed - are you sure to run this with a final generated container? Which PHP version are you using?

Comment: I used  php 5 before and updated to php7 with the same results. Sorry, but do you mean with 'final generated container'?.  Is the profiller in the view of a clean sf instalation with one bundle. Maybe the twig templates could be more efficents but  dumping memory_get_peak_usage() in controller give me a similar result.

Comment: Dumping the Symfony container is more sophisticated in recent Symfony versions, so this takes more time and memory. But if you want to see clear data, you should check out tools like XDebug, XHProf or Blackfire. They will help you spot problems in your code - which we haven't even seen